# Filtering Selection from AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is, I want to display the selection that registered under `accType=Acc1` in `Selection`. The `AccInfo` function is my ajax call. I would like to pass the parameter in `data`. The `Acc_response` function is a function to operate the option value. I would like to show the `branchCode`,`accType`,`Code`, that is registered under `Acc1`. How can I do that?

```
function AccInfo(Acc1){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        datatype:"json",
        async:true,
        data:{A:Acc1},
        url:AccInfo_url,
        success: function(data){
            Acc_response(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            errorHandling(textStatus);
        }
    })
}

function Acc_response(data){
    console.log(data);
    for (var i=0;i<data.ClientInfo.length;i++)
    {
        var $option=$('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', data.ClientInfo[i].branchCode+"|"+data.ClientInfo[i].Code+"|"+data.ClientInfo[i].accType);
        $option.text(data.ClientInfo[i].accType+" (" + data.ClientInfo[i].Code+"-"+data.ClientInfo[i].branchCode+") ";
        $('#Selection').append($option);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had fixed that but nothing happens the selection shows all option from all accType

Comment: check your response in the network tab

Comment: It seems that your server is returning too much information, then.

Comment: Where are you trying to filter? On server or client?

Comment: `var $option=$('<option />');` remove the `/` from option

Comment: How can I display the selection registered under AccType1 only?

Comment: are u using a microsoft .net framework ?? if you are you should access the data through (data.d.ClientInfo)

Comment: No.. I didn't use microsoft.net. How to do this in Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This is more usefull;

```
        var selectedAccType = 'your account type';
        //you can set this at post action to
        function Acc_response(data){
              data.ClientInfo.forEach(function(client) {
                if(client.accType==selectedAccType){
                    var optionValue = client.branchCode+'|'+client.Code+'|'+client.accType;
                    var optionText = client.accType+'('client.Code+'-'+client.branchCode+')';
                    var option = '<option value="'+optionValue+'">'+optionText+'</option>';
                    $('#Selection').append(option);
                }
              });
            }
```

This works for if you have one `<select>`. If you have more selects send us your html code.

Comment: Where do you filter the data?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. In example do you have two user (acc) and they have different client info? And you want to add this infos to user which have these infos

Comment: Okay..Let me explain to you.

Comment: And please share your html struct.

Comment: I have a user which have multiple accType. A user may have AccType1 and AccType2.Each accType have different code, branch code. What I want to do right now I want to filter the selection to show the option ONLY for AccType 1. I want to pass the parameter from ajax call. and the Acc_response function will populate the option.

Comment: why shd I put selectedAccType? I would like to show the AccType1 Selection automatically

Comment: Your post action must have to it not js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76414/discussion-between-nur-wafiqa-and-hurricane).